# Slow boot on Fedora 24

Tags: linux, boot, performance, fedora

Last week, I installed Fedora 24. Previously, on the same computer, I was using Fedora 22 (Fedora 24 is a clean installation, not a package upgrade).

What surprised me is that Fedora 24 is booting really slow in comparison with 22. The installation is/was the default one - I haven't changed anything in the system configuration. See the ouput of `systemd-analyze`:

```
Startup finished in 1.329s (kernel) + 4.189s (initrd) + 1min 31.811s (userspace) = 1min 37.330s
```

I don't know how much time Fedora 22 was taking but I am pretty sure it was under 30 seconds...

Now see what `systemd-analyze blame` says:

```
     14.949s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      9.598s systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-luks\x2d0efbd95c\x2d4199\x2d4060\x2d83de\x2da992a5c3f72a.service
      7.884s systemd-cryptsetup@luks\x2d0efbd95c\x2d4199\x2d4060\x2d83de\x2da992a5c3f72a.service
      6.710s systemd-cryptsetup@luks\x2d09638d45\x2d10af\x2d4db9\x2db21f\x2d79a4a80d6a31.service
      5.229s firewalld.service
      3.644s systemd-udev-settle.service
      3.246s dev-mapper-system\x2droot.device
      2.635s udisks2.service
      2.399s accounts-daemon.service
      1.790s polkit.service
      1.647s abrtd.service
      1.646s lvm2-monitor.service
      1.547s proc-fs-nfsd.mount
      1.542s plymouth-start.service
      1.162s systemd-fsck-root.service
      1.159s systemd-binfmt.service
      1.152s systemd-rfkill.service
      1.146s ModemManager.service
      1.099s lvm2-pvscan@8:5.service
      1.064s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       971ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
       934ms systemd-journald.service
       781ms fedora-readonly.service
       713ms cups.service
       561ms gssproxy.service
       487ms systemd-random-seed.service
       450ms NetworkManager.service
       403ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       401ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
       395ms avahi-daemon.service
       392ms systemd-udevd.service
       369ms abrt-ccpp.service
       334ms systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-luks\x2d09638d45\x2d10af\x2d4db9\x2db21f\x2d79a4a80d6a31.service
       311ms systemd-sysctl.service
       306ms auditd.service
       272ms fedora-import-state.service
       272ms user@42.service
       269ms colord.service
       267ms rtkit-daemon.service
       267ms wpa_supplicant.service
       248ms user@1000.service
       245ms dmraid-activation.service
       235ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       231ms upower.service
       225ms home.mount
       206ms systemd-logind.service
       201ms gdm.service
       199ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       164ms dev-mqueue.mount
       163ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       161ms dev-hugepages.mount
       145ms plymouth-read-write.service
       137ms dev-mapper-system\x2dswap.swap
```

Could you please help me to find out the problem and fix it? I don't know what should I check now... but I don't think that some of the values above are normal.

UPDATE: I updated `systemd-analyze` output for a case when I try to enter the passwords really, really fast, without any delay.

UPDATE 2: I would like to add that the booting screen looks fine to some point. After I type the encryption passwords, the white logo (which is some kind of progress bar) is displayed for some time and then it switches to normal Fedora logo and that is displayed for a minute

UPDATE 3: My `journalctl -b` output is here: http://pastebin.com/vjZypBz0

Comment: You are using encrypted partitions?

Comment: Yes. These are logical volumes. (I have quite complicated structure for a desktop - two physical disks with two volume groups and some physical partitions... However, I was running the same on Fedora 22.)

Comment: My `journalctl -b` output is here: http://pastebin.com/vjZypBz0

Answer (score 0):

Boot of Fedora 25 is fast (or at least faster) again. On the same HW, booting takes only 30 seconds. I have never found what was wrong with 24... :-(

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  So this means that the original question is moot at this point?

Comment: For me, it is...